# Docker - Could not load X509 key pair

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am on a fresh install of Docker on OSX El Capitain 10.11.4. I am getting this error when I try any commands with docker.

```
Could not load X509 key pair: crypto/tls: private key does not match public key. Make sure the key is not encrypted
```

I can run docker-machine just fine, but not start any docker containers.

Docker version (the only docker command that is working so far)

```
Brunos-iMac:~ brunoban$ docker -v
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd
```

Docker machine version

```
Brunos-iMac:~ brunoban$ docker-machine -v
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
```

Docker machine ls

```
Brunos-iMac:~ brunoban$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                              SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.10.3
```

Docker machine env

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export   DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/brunoban/.docker/machine/machines/default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(docker-machine env)
```

I tried regenerating the certs with docker-machine regenerate-certs (even with the --force flag), but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone shed a light?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a bit more details about your env? The certificate issue is occuring to you when you try to access your swarm manager? node?

Comment: @buddy123 It happens when I use any command to manage a container. A simple docker ps or docker run returns that command. I am relatively new to docker, which other env details would help?

Comment: @brunoban, did you find a workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: Hey @joss, It's been a while but I think I uninstalled everything, tried to purge anything related to docker from the environment and reinstalled it from scratch. I haven't had a similar problem since.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** My scenario is different from the original question, but my error message is the same.

I get the same error message when I try to add a new stack using the Portainer UI and a composition file.

My scenario is configured as follows:

- Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS as O.S. host;
- Docker-ce version: 19.03.13 (API: 1.40)
- Portainer-ce (2.0.0);
- Portainer Agent (2.0.0);

My docker-compose.yaml using portainer/agent(it doesn't work like that)

```yaml
    version: '2'
    
    services:
    
        portainer_agent:
            image: portainer/agent
            container_name: task.agent
            volumes:
                - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
                - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes
            ports:
                - "9001:9001"
            networks:
                - agent_network
            restart: always
    
        # The portainer instance for managing Docker containers locally
        # To run on localhost in standalone mode
        # https://documentation.portainer.io/v2.0/deploy/linux/#docker-standalone
        portainer:
            image: portainer/portainer-ce
            command: -H tcp://task.agent:9001 --tlsskipverify
            volumes:
                - portainer_data:/data
                - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
                - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes
            ports:
                - "8000:8000"
                - "9000:9000"
            networks:
                - agent_network
            restart: always
    
    networks:
      agent_network:
        attachable: true
    
    volumes:
        portainer_data:
```

Now, I realized that the goal of the portainer agent is to provide an alternative solution for executing commands when the docker is running as a cluster. In standalone mode, the agent is not required.

Looking at the [official documentation of Portainer in the "Docker Standalone" session](https://documentation.portainer.io/v2.0/deploy/linux/#docker-standalone), I found the following:

"Use the following Docker commands to deploy the Portainer Server; note that the agent is not required on independent hosts, however, it does provide additional functionality if used (see Portainer and agent scenario below):"

**The solution for my scenario**

So, I just run Portainer without an Agent and when I deploy any stack using the Portainer UI, it's working fine.

I hope this helps someone who has the same error message.